# Provisioning a Vagrant box: are provisioners installed on the guest or the host machine?

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I have a basic interrogation about Vagrant (and the Ansible provisioner).

Is Ansible (or any other provisioner for that matter) **installed on the guest machine or on the host machine?**

In other words, is there a requirement for Ansible to be installed on the host machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible runs on the host and sends ssh commands to the guest. (See @leucos answer)

Puppet-agent runs on the guest and parses a catalog (manifest) that is provided.

Ansible can also run on the guest and do pulls.

Only Ansible up to now can run **only** on the host.

The rest of the provisioners like PUPPET, CHEF, CRFENGINE etc **need an agent** on the guest mostly.

Comment: Thank a lot Jimmy: if I understand you well, I don't need the requirement for the Ansible dependency on the host and run Ansible only on the guest using pulls? If that is the case, can you please point to relevant documentation on how to set up this configuration?

Comment: @balteo check here for a tutorial http://www.stavros.io/posts/automated-large-scale-deployments-ansibles-pull-mo/ and here for the original info http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html

Answer (score 1):

The provisionner runs on the hypervisor (the host machine). The vagrant ansible provisionner will generate an inventory file if you don't provide one.

Thus, you don't need to install ansible on your vagrant guests.

However, there might be some requirements on your vagrant guest with certain modules (e.g. `python-apt`, `python-mysqldb`, etc...).

The requirements are listed in each module documentation.

Good luck